# How can i use a complete endpoint URL to make a retrofit call, instead of using base/relative URLs?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have to make a post request using retrofit, but the URL for this request comes from another request (GET), and the URL comes as a complete endpoint (i.e: `https://pod-000-1005-03.backblaze.com/b2api/v2/b2_upload_file?cvt=c001_v0001005_t0027&bucket=4a48fe8875c6214145260818`).

How can i make a retrofit request directly to this endpoint?

How im creating the retrofit instance:

```
fun getUploadApi(uploadUrl: String): B2UploadApi {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(uploadUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(B2UploadApi::class.java)
    }
```

- this throws an exception since the url doesnt end with '`/`'

And the `POST` request:

```
@POST
    suspend fun uploadFile(
        @Header("Authorization") authToken: String,
        @Header("X-Bz-File-Name") fileName: String,
        @Header("Content-Length") fileSize: Int,
        @Header("Content-Type") mimeType: String,
        @Header("X-Bz-Content-Sha1") sha1: String,
        @Body byteArray: ByteArray
    ): Response<UploadResponse>
```

Comment: Have you tried [a `@Url` parameter](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Url.html) on the `uploadFile()` function?

Comment: @CommonsWare for what i saw, i should pass the endpoint as a parameter annotated with this URL to the function, but then what should i pass as the baseUrl when creating the retrofit instance? will this `@Url ` override it?

Comment: "what should i pass as the baseUrl when creating the retrofit instance?" -- you already have a Retrofit instance, I assume ("he URL for this request comes from another request (GET)"). So, use that Retrofit instance, rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in documentation , @url will override base url which you have mentioned at time of retrofit object creation

So you just need to use @url annotation along with method in retrofit service

documentation - https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Url.html

example -

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-use-dynamic-urls-for-requests